# Hashicorp Vault SSL Subject Alternative Name in certificates

Tags: ssl, certificate, hashicorp-vault

Dear stackoverflow community,

we're looking for a solution for generating SSL server and client certificates with HashiCorp vault like this:

> X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: DNS:myhostname.mydomain.com,
> DNS:myhostname

Basically we just want to add as many DNS entries/hostnames as we want to the certificate.

What we achieved so far is that Vault generates the certificate SAN like this:

> X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: DNS:foobar.mydomain.com, URI:foobar,
> URI:barfoo

```
Vault CLI command:  vault write pki/issue/server common_name="foobar.mydomain.com" ttl=2h alt_names="foobar,barfoo"
```

Any chance to get the first version running with vault? We're struggling to find the correct parameter or even the correct way to achieve this.

Could spend someone a little effort and time explaining this to us?

Many thanks and best regards
Matt

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to use Vault to sign certificates with URI alternate names.

The relevant documentation [is here](https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/secret/pki#sign-certificate)...

There are two parts to it.

1. you have to have a PKI role that allows the URI sans, use the `allowed_uri_sans` property when you create the *"server"* role - you'll need to allow each of the alternate names.
2. when you use vault to issue the cert, supply a `uri_sans` argument.

The vault command would look something like:

```sh
vault write pki/issue/server common_name="foobar.mydomain.com" ttl=2h uri_sans="foobar,barfoo"
```